# How to get the key-value from an object in JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, object, multidimensional-array

I have a success function that gets an object:

```
success: function(json) {

}
```

`json` is `[>Object , >Object , >Object, ...]`

inside each object i have some keys and values:

```
object[
    test: yes
    testing: no
]
```

i am trying to get those values and the keys and place them in a div element:

```
for ( var object in json)
{
    for ( var objects in json[object])
    {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json[object][objects]);
        $('#details').append(obj);
    }
}
```

this will give me all values from all objects one after each other mashed together. I want to be able to know the keys also so i can arrange them a bit in a table or something any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have it done already, `objects` should be the keys:

```
for ( var object in json)
{
    for ( var objects in json[object])
    {
        //here `objects` will be a key
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json[object][objects]);
        $('#details').append(obj);
    }
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/FmDU9/1/

On a side-note: `for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++){` is much faster than `for ( var object in json)` so if you are iterating through an array of objects, use `for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++){` to iterate through the array. Here is some proof of this: http://jsperf.com/for-in-tests/2

Comment: one more thing if you don't mind. How do you know witch one is witch. what if i want to select only a certain value? ex: testing from your example

Comment: @Patrioticcow If you know the key you want to access you can check against the current key: `if (objects == 'testing') {...}`. If you are working with known keys (they are always the same) then I suggest getting rid of the inner `for` loop and just accessing the values like this: `$('#details').append('testing = ' + json[object].testing + '<br />test = ' . json[object].test);`